# There is currently no icinga instance writing to the IDO

Tags: monitoring, icinga

Hi i have installer icinga2 and icingaweb2 from official docs:

icinga2: 
http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#setting-up-icinga2

and icingaweb2: https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/blob/master/doc/installation.md

During setup process, when set the monitoring module in the "Monitoring IDO resource" page, i insert the credentials of database an i have this error:

`There is currently no icinga instance writing to the IDO. Make sure that a icinga instance is configured and able to write to the IDO.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved, need edit the file `/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/ido-mysql.conf` and insert db/user/passwd

My file is:

```
library "db_ido_mysql"

object IdoMysqlConnection "ido-mysql" {
  user = "icinga",
  password = "password",
  host = "localhost",
  database = "icinga"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On Debian systems, after the default installation and configuration of the IDO package, this file is actually pre-generated in `/etc/icinga2/features-available/ido-pgsql.conf` or similar, you just need to symlink it into `/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/`, and restart the icinga2 service.