# Icingaweb2 mysql-ido setup warning: safe to proceed?

Tags: icinga2, debian-stretch

I'm doing a test run of Icinga2 as a replacement for my shop's Nagios system, but like many others I've run into some trouble with the set-up of the web ui.

It's at the database setup, which seems to be especially troublesome if you're running Debian Stretch on account of Stretch blocking the ui from building the database for you. This means it's necessary to pre-configure the db, and then feed that db's info to the web ui. Following Icinga's own instructions, I did this (being sure to import the schema, of course) and on clicking "Validate", I get the dreaded

```
There is currently no icinga instance writing to the IDO. Make sure that a icinga instance is configured and able to write to the IDO.
```

It's orange, not red, so I suppose it's not a fatal error. But, since this is destined for a production environment, I need to know if skipping the validation and proceeding will be a problem later. Icinga's own docs on ido-mysql aren't very forthcoming.

I found [There is currently no icinga instance writing to the IDO](https://serverfault.com/questions/743426/there-is-currently-no-icinga-instance-writing-to-the-ido) and duplicated those steps, but it had no effect on the error. This happened with no difference on two different clean installs of Debian Stretch (which makes me want to switch to CentOS7 for this project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions. It's always permissions.

Make sure features-available/ido-mysql.conf is set to 660. On a clean Debian Stretch install and following the official docs to the letter, that file is made with 440, which prevents writing.